# update some documents and one document of them with a different property

Tags: mongodb

I need update some documents and one document of them with a different property
this its my idea.

```
db.collectin.update({ 
    $and : 
      [{ _id : { $in: ['fenix', 'napoleon', 'patascoy'] },  },
      {  _id : 'fenix'      }]
    },
    {
      $inc: { 'info.p1' : one },
      $inc: { 'info.p2' : one } 
    });
```

but updates in mongodb not using $and operator

i have these documents

```
{
  _id: 'fenix',
  info:{
    p1: 0,
    p2: 0 
  }
},
{
  _id: 'napoleon',
  info:{
    p1: 0,
    p2: 0 
  }},
  {
  _id: 'patascoy',
  info:{
    p1: 0,
    p2: 0 
  }
}
```

I need to update all the documents in the vector by adding one in the property `p1` and document whit `_id:fenix` update with one more in p2

```
{
  _id: 'fenix',
  info:{
    p1: 1,
    p2: 1 
  }
},
{
  _id: 'napoleon',
  info:{
    p1: 1,
    p2: 0 
  }},
  {
  _id: 'patascoy',
  info:{
    p1: 1,
    p2: 0 
  }
}
```

Comment: Mention clearly at least one sample document which you want to update and what you want to update in that document , adding expected result is much better.

Comment: I already edited it